# HTTP Status 503 - This application is not currently available when deploying

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, http-status-code-503

I was using netbeans 8 and Glassfish 4 originally.  The server that was purchased for this application is a tomcat server, so I installed Tomcat 8 and tested it.  I realized in my first deploy when I got this error that it was a Tomcat 6.0.36 server, so I went into netbeans changed my servlet specification to 2.5, Java to 7, to make it work, but I still get the same error.

I do notice I have 2 files that were created called "web-fragment.xml" that uses the servlet spec 3.1 and not 2.5 that I need.

It says that these started coming out with servlet 3.0, I guess since i'm using Netbeans 8 with the latest stuff it's going be the 3.1 spec, but I want to know how to get rid of these files?  I read up that they don't impact my .WAR file, but I'm still having an issue, so I'm curious if anyone has any idea what it could be?

According to the server this is my log

```
RROR main org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry - Null component Catalina:type=JspMonitor,name=jsp,WebModule="mysite.com",J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
ERROR main org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Error deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: plan/ViewerServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class plan.ViewerServlet)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1078)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
ERROR main org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry - Null component Catalina:type=JspMonitor,name=jsp,WebModule=//planogrammer.com/,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
ERROR main org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Error deploying web application archive ROOT.war
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: plan/ViewerServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class plan.ViewerServlet)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1078)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on your servlet version, but in the compiled version of your classes and the JVM that you are running it.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0).

Comment: Thanks, basically as I said I went from Netbeans 8 and have to use Java 6 on this server.  I did realize I was originally using 1.7 and went down to 6 and my application runs fine except for this servlet issue.

I get a couple issues, mainly having to do with the root folder, but the last is this.

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

According to the link you provided 51 is 1.7, while I am using a 1.6 server.

I changed the sources in netbeans to 1.6, which is what others are suggesting, but nothing....  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The web.xml file (and its fragments) do go into war and have to be read by the servlet container (just unzip a war to confirm).

So you effectively had two different problems :

- java version since tomcat 6 only accepted 1.6 (java 6)
- servlet version since tomcat 6 only support servlet 2.5 that do not allow fragments

So if you really want to use tomcat 6.0.36, you will have to find all your web-fragment.xml and put them in main web.xml